# wp_query->max_num_pages always returns 0 on custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an issue with my pagination that seems to stem from the fact that `$wp_query->max_num_pages` returns `0`.

I believe that this is due to have `0` default wordpress posts.

So, I am using the [WP Download Manager Pro plugin](https://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/) that creates a custom post type `wpdmpro`.

I have pages for each category, and using the loop, I loop through each post with a `post-type` of `wpdmpro`.

```
<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 2,
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'post_type' => 'wpdmpro', 
        'wpdmcategory' => $category->category_nicename,
        'tag' => $cat_tag
    );
    query_posts($args)
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
   /* content goes here */
<?php endif; ?>
<?php else : ?>

    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
        <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

```
echo $wp_query->max_num_pages /* returns 0 */
echo $wp_query->found_posts   /* returns 0 */
```

Although, I actually have `11` posts in the `wpdmpro` `post_type`. So why do the echos not doing the following?

```
echo $wp_query->max_num_pages /* Should return 2 because I have 11 posts with 10 per page */
echo $wp_query->found_posts   /* Shoudl return 11 because I have 11 posts */
```

Tried the following to see if this would work

```
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'action_pre_get_posts' );
  function action_pre_get_posts( $q ) 
  {
    $q->set('max_num_pages', 20);
  }
```

But when navigating to `page/2/` I still get a 404 page.

The url I am hitting is `/category-name/page/2` which returns a `404`.

There must be a solution to this?

How do I make my site ignore the default WordPress post types and use what I actually define, the `wpdmpro` post types?

Edit:
I have tried to use the `WP_Query` class too, but still hitting a 404 page when navigating to `/page/2`

Just a few things to add in case they are somehow linked.

In my permalinks settings, I have a custom structure of

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

and my default category base is `.`

In my WP Download Manager Settings, my `WPDM Category URL Base` is `.`

I also have these 2 filter functions, that were copied from answers on here, and I am quite new to Wordpress so I am not sure of the potential repercussions of using these are?

```
add_filter('category_rewrite_rules', 'vipx_filter_category_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'remove_category', 100, 2);
```

```
function vipx_filter_category_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => false));

    if (is_array($categories) && !empty($categories)) {
        $slugs = array();
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            if (is_object($category) && !is_wp_error($category)) {
                if (0 == $category - > category_parent) {
                    $slugs[] = $category - > slug;
                } else {
                    $slugs[] = trim(get_category_parents($category - > term_id, false, '/', true), '/');
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($slugs)) {
            $rules = array();

            foreach($slugs as $slug) {
                $rules['('.$slug.
                    ')/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)?/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
                $rules['('.$slug.
                    ')/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
                $rules['('.$slug.
                    ')(/page/(\d+)/?)?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]';
            }
        }
    }
    return $rules;
}

function remove_category($string, $type) {
    if ($type != 'single' && $type == 'category' && (strpos($string, 'category') !== false)) {
        $url_without_category = str_replace("/wpdmcategory/", "/", $string);
        return trailingslashit($url_without_category);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

I also ensured that none of the posts slugs were conflicting with the category name.

Answer (score 4):

Also... make sure you don't have `no_found_rows` set to `true` in your WP_Query args.

Answer (score 1):

You should really avoid `query_posts()` when you can, opting for the [`WP_Query` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) instead. Something like this:

```
<?php
// Args
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 2,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'post_type'         => 'wpdmpro', 
    'wpdmcategory'      => $category->category_nicename,
    'tag'               => $cat_tag
);

// Query
$wpdmpro_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if( $wpdmpro_query->have_posts() ) : while( $wpdmpro_query->have_posts() ) : $wpdmpro_query->the_post();
?>
    <!-- Do stuff -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- Do stuff if there are no posts -->

endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And then to test `max_num_pages` you'd use the query:

```
echo $wpdmpro_query->max_num_pages
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I did try the `WP_Query` class, but hitting `/page/2/` still gives me a 404, regardless of what I use

Comment: Updated my answer with my permalinks etc.

Comment: Hm - well switching back to the class would definitely be step 1, but you might try removing those two filters and re-saving the Permalinks settings to flush the rewrite rules and see if it works. If not then check to make sure the Query variable (`$wpdmpro_query` in my case) is included in the pagination links. [This post may help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189247/why-pagination-is-not-working-and-gives-a-404-error-on-the-wordpress-site)

Comment: I remove the filters and flushed the rewrite rules, but no luck, unfortunately. Also, unsure for to check the variable in the pagination links. I had been using ```<?php next_posts_link('<span aria-hidden="true"></span> Older Entries') ?>```

Comment: Ah. If you've switched back to the class, try `<?php next_posts_link( '<span aria-hidden="true"></span> Older Entries' , $wpdmpro_query->max_num_pages ); ?>`

Comment: Still having the issue where `/page/2/` does not exist, regardless of how I get to that page, hardcoded, typing in the url, or using the above snippet. Where can it possibly be thinking I am using the default post type and not my custom post type? It's very confusing as to why it chooses the default post type.

Comment: If you do `echo $wpdmpro_query->max_num_pages` does it still return `0`?

Comment: No, it does return the correct value now, still does not fix my issue

Comment: This is a new and separate issue than the original question then. I'd recommend [searching around](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+pagination+404&oq=wordpress+pagination+404&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60l3.4340j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for the new issue and then posting a separate question if you can't figure it out, as there could be many possible causes. You're on the right track, though! Maybe try changing your permalink structure first and see if any of the others work.

Comment: I do realise this. This has been 2 days of searching, but I will continue. Thanks for your help

Comment: Found a solution that I have submitted as an answer. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This function let you find the number of custom posts you have :

```
$num_posts = wp_count_posts('your_custom_post_type')->publish;
```

(cf. [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_posts/) )

So, you can obtain the `max_num_pages` value through a simple operation between this and the `posts_per_page` value :

```
$max_num_pages = $num_posts / $your_posts_per_page;
if ($num_posts % $your_posts_per_page > 0) $max_num_pages++;
```

Comment: thanks! there's an easiear way to know if you are at the end of the pagination: $posts->max_num_pages == $pagination

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever stumbles across this, I found the solution.

First step was to create an `archive.php` page

In there I would access the loop.

The in `functions.php`

I have a category rewrite filter to update the category rewrite rules to use the following example url `index.php?wpdmcategory=category-name&paged=2` when I hit `/category-name/page/2`

Previously, it was using the following example url, `index.php?category_name=category-name&paged=2` so it was actually using the default post type for the category paging.

```
add_filter( 'category_rewrite_rules', 'vipx_filter_category_rewrite_rules' );`

function vipx_filter_category_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $categories = get_terms('wpdmcategory', array("hide_empty" => false));

    if (is_array($categories) && !empty($categories)) {
        $slugs = array();
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            if (is_object($category) && !is_wp_error($category)) {
                if (0 == $category - > category_parent) {
                    $slugs[] = $category - > slug;
                } else {
                    $slugs[] = trim(get_category_parents($category - > term_id, false, '/', true), '/');
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($slugs)) {
            $rules = array();

            foreach($slugs as $slug) {
                $rules['('.$slug.
                    ')/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)?/?$'] = 'index.php?wpdmcategory=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
                $rules['('.$slug.
                    ')/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?wpdmcategory=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
                $rules['('.$slug.
                    ')(/page/(\d+)/?)?$'] = 'index.php?wpdmcategory=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]';
            }
        }
    }
    return $rules;
}
```