# Wordpress Custom Post Type Pagination 404

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I know, this question has been asked a lot. I have been through a lot of them already, but my issue seems to be more bespoke.

Initially, I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58183593/wp-query-max-num-pages-always-returns-0-on-custom-post-type) issue, but seems to be another issue, therefore I am asking a new question in hopes for a solution.

I am using the [WP Download Manager Pro plugin](https://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/) that creates a custom post type `wpdmpro`.

So, the crux of my issue seems to be that my pagination in my `loop.php`, seems to be connected someone to the default post type and not the custom post type I am using, as in, if I have `0` Posts in my default posts, navigating to `/page/2` will not work, but if I have `11` default posts it will, but then `/page/3` will not work.

I have `11` `wpdmpro` posts and `0` default posts. Therefore, I would expect here, that with 2 posts per page, that I would have 6 pages? Wordpress seems to think differently!

Here is my query

```
<?php
$category = get_queried_object(); 
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 2,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'post_type'         => 'wpdmpro', 
    'wpdmcategory'      => $category->category_nicename,
    'tag'               => $cat_tag
);

// Query
$wpdmpro_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if( $wpdmpro_query->have_posts() ) : while( $wpdmpro_query->have_posts() ) : $wpdmpro_query->the_post();
?>
    <!-- Do stuff -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- Do stuff if there are no posts -->

endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

So WHY does `/page/2` return a `404` when that page SHOULD exist? As mentioned, if I start to add posts to the default post (on the 11th post), then `/page/2` seems to work, with the 21st post `/page/3/` works, so it has to be linked to that. But why? I clearly define that I am NOT using `'post_type' => 'post',`. So where could this be defined and how can I override it?

Just a few things to add in case they are somehow linked.

In my permalinks settings, I have a custom structure of

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

and my default category base is `.`

I have tried resetting the permalinks settings, but still getting the 404 page on `/page/2`.

In my WP Download Manager Settings, my `WPDM Category URL Base` is `.`

So, with all that my url is.

`{domain}/category-name/page/2/` which is returning the 404.

`{domain}/category-name/` returns 2 posts of the stated category.

Part of me is concerned this is a configuration issue, mixing a custom post type with custom structure and category base. Someone out there must have had this issue? It seems like this should be very simple, but I cannot for the life of me find a solution, perhaps I am looking in the wrong places?

Any help will be massively appreciated.

Edit:

I have tried to regenerate the permalinks on multiple different occassions to no effect.

Comment: do you have tried to regenerate the permalink after a new custom post type is added? go in settings->permalinks and click on the button at the bottom of page

Comment: Yes! No luck with that. I've honestly probably done it a hundred different times

Comment: try to replace ` 'posts_per_page'    => 2,`  with `$default_posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );` value

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still does not change the fact that `/page/2/` does not exist and that it's still tied to the default posts and not to my custom type posts.

Comment: even if you change to 2 the default post per page value in settings -> reading

Comment: Already done that, changed it back to 10. Still should have a page 2, as I have 11 custom type posts. I would list everything I have done but it would be a long, long question. This has been 2 days worth of searching and hundreds of potential solutions on StackExchange.

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738362/how-to-include-pagination-in-a-wordpress-custom-post-type-query if you don't already read it

Comment: Found a solution that I have submitted as an answer. Thank you for your help!