# How to fix wordpress pagination redirect?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am using pagination in wordpress `category.php` page. everthing is fine but when I click to next page **i got following error**

`Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a index.php template file. Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet.`

My url is some thing like

```
https://test.com/category/cat_name/page/2/
```

**Here is my code:**

```
    $cat_name = $category->name;
      $cat_id   = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
      $temp = $wp_query;
      $wp_query = null;
      $wp_query = new WP_Query();
      $wp_query->query('showposts=1&post_type=post&paged='.$paged.'&cat='.$cat_id);
      while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
/// loop here
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Code for pagination:**

```
<?php
  global $wp_query;
 
  $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
  echo '<div class="custom-pagination">';
    echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'prev_text' => __('Previous'),
    'next_text' => __('Next'),
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
  echo '</div>';
?>
```

Should I add some code in htaccess file or function.php for redirect in category.php?

Comment: Note that WordPress often redirects content when it might otherwise generate a 404 error, so considering those solutions also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189247/why-pagination-is-not-working-and-gives-a-404-error-on-the-wordpress-site

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by my self. I need to change the `Blog pages show at most` in reading section of Dashboard. I set same number of `showposts` i.e 1 in `Blog pages show at most`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution, I was going crazy!