# pagination in wordpress throw error 404 when i go to page/2

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have a problem.

I try with many many solutions, some of them:

1. Clean the permalinks of any extra category
2. Disable all plugins and reactivate it one by one.
3. Add this code in functions.php

```php
function modify_product_cat_query($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_tax("ford_escort")){
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 10);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_product_cat_query' );
```

Nothing of this works.... the url generated by the page one is http://localhost:10004/page/2
As you can see, i don´t see any extra categorie in the middle...
Can you help me please?
I´m using the latest version of Wordpress and PHP 8.1.9

I have this code for a custom taxonomy, i need paginate it.

```
<?php
    $paged = get_query_var('ford_escort') ? get_query_var("") : 1;

    // Custom query arguments for pagination
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'escort',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'paged' => $paged,
     );

    // Create a custom query
    $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Now you can loop through the posts
    if ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
        $custom_query->the_post();
        // Display post content here
        echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore original post data

    // Display pagination links
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'total' => $custom_query->max_num_pages,`your text`
        'current' => $paged,
        'prev_next' => false,
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'),
        'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'),
    ));

   }
   ?>
```

The pages appears but when i choose the whathever of the pages i receive a 404 page error.

Comment: "I have this code for a custom taxonomy, I need paginate it" - if you have a custom taxonomy, there's a free template called `template-{taxonomy}.php` you can be using, and WordPress will take care of the URLs for you automatically, and you can tweak the per-page as your first example, no need for a dedicated custom query.

Comment: `$paged = get_query_var('ford_escort') ? get_query_var("") : 1;` - what did you expect `get_query_var("")` to return here ...? And why are you checking whether a query var named `ford_escort` is set in this scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why pagination is not working and gives a 404 error on the wordpress site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189247/why-pagination-is-not-working-and-gives-a-404-error-on-the-wordpress-site)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue causing the 404 error on the pagination page is that WordPress thinks the page should not exist. This could be due to a default setting of a different number of posts per page or an incorrect post type being used. To resolve this problem, you can make changes to the $wp_query using pre_get_posts.

Please, try to add this code on functions.php in your theme:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && is_tax('ford_escort') && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged') ?: 1;
        $query->set('paged', $paged);
        $query->set('post_type', 'escort');
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 50);
    }
});
```

And change your code on this:

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ?: 1;
// Custom query arguments for pagination
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'escort',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

// Create a custom query
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

// Now you can loop through the posts
if ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
        $custom_query->the_post();
        // Display post content here
        echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore original post data

    // Display pagination links
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'total' => $custom_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $paged,
        'prev_next' => false,
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'),
        'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'),
    ));
}
?>
```

Also, I recommend you flush rewrite rules. You can do this in the admin area under "Settings > Permalinks." Just click on the "Save Changes" button, or you can use the function flush_rewrite_rules(). However, you should be careful when using this function since it can be slow, and you should only use it very rarely (only when you want to regenerate rewrite rules).

Comment: Can you explain (in your answer, not to me) how this code solves the OP's problem?

Comment: I have added some notes. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to help people understand my recommendations. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I can't validate this one way or another, we just always strongly encourage having more than "try this code" for answers. At a quick glance this makes sense and hopefully helps the OP. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! This is valuable and useful to me. I will try to give more detailed answers in the future. I also hope my recommendations will be useful for the OP. Thanks!